# Two network cards, choose which to use with each Java application?

Tags: java, networking

I have a pc with two network cards, I do web testing using htmlunit, is there anyway to run 2 htmlunit instances and pick which instance uses which network card?

Regards!

Comment: I would take a look at [`NetworkInterface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding to a client socket or opening a server socket, specify an explicit local IP address to choose the adapter.  The `java.net.NetworkInterface` API provides methods to enumerate adapters and get their IPs